# How to check for duplicates before saving the data into the database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, insert

I have the below codes to insert into my guest table in my database. How do I add an if statement to check for duplicates using the guest_id before I can proceed to my next page to save?

```
$query = "
    INSERT INTO guest(
        guest_id, guestName, guestNameLast, salutation, 
        country, state, contact_no, cardNumber, expiryDate, 
        cardName, cardType, guest_date
    ) VALUES (
        '" . $guest_id . "',
        '" . $guestName . "',
        '" . $guestNameLast . "',
        '" . $salutation . "',
        '" . $country . "',
        '" . $state . "',
        '" . $contact_no . "',
        '" . $cardNumber . "',
        '" . $expiryDate . "',
        '" . $cardName . "',
        '" . $cardType . "',
        '" . $guest_date . "'
    )";
```

Do help me, thank you. :)

Comment: [***Have you tried anything?***](http://whathaveyoutried.com) You can search for the values before inserting, or you can create a unique index to prevent duplicate data from being inserted (and catch any attempt made to insert duplicate data). Do some research

Answer (score 2):

Try insead `INSERT INTO table ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` Syntax, but first make sure your `guest_id` is a `Primary Key` or `UNIQUE` index
see here:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 1):

You can make `guest_id` a primary key and then try to insert it. That way you just try to insert and if it doesn't work it means the id already exists.
You can check that by seeing what your function returns.

Comment: You can also make the `guest_id` field a `UNIQUE` index

Comment: Hmm... this would be like hitting the wall and then discovering you have hit a wall, jus sayin.

Comment: i like doing it this way because it requires less code. You can also use  an other query to check if the id exist and then decide to proceed with the insert query or not.

Comment: If I would like a message to prompt out as duplicate user, instead of the database letting me know of duplicate entry 'xxxx' for key 'PRIMARY'?

Comment: @WhirlMind depending on the application, you may not want the overhead of a separate query to see if the record exists first

Comment: and btw you should use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements to avoid sql injections

Comment: The usual insert statement and added this in, but it displays as an sql injection.
$query2 = "SELECT guest_id FROM guest WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM guest WHERE guest_id = $guest_id)";
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($link));

Comment: @Machavity : That would be better than something hitting the database (or trying to hit) and then reverting with a native error from the DBMS and then having to handle the error. It would be best to do a check and prepare for a clear expected result rather than reacting to an unexpected result. But yes, as you say, I agree it should depend on the application. I must have come from SQL Server, where the EXISTS query takes lesser overhead than a Count query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(guest_id) as MyGuestIdCount from guest where guest_id = $guest_id
```

Run this query and if it fetches > 0 then the guest_id already exists. 
You can also use the EXISTS functionality

http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/exists.php

Answer (score 0):

The guest_id would have been set as primary key to prevent insertion of existing guest_id's, how to find out on the PHP side? do this:

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
    echo "New guest record inserted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are alternative ways for it

1. make primary key and try to insert, so it will raise error if data
   is already there
2. Fire select before with the unique identifier or specific data before inserting your